# which DOM element binded to my Backbone view?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I am reading codes:

```
module.exports = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'div',
  events: {
    'keydown': '_enter',
  }
  ...
```

The tagName is "div", How can I know which div this is?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el):

> **el** `view.el`
>   [...]
>   `this.el` can be resolved from a DOM selector string or an Element; otherwise it will be created from the view's `tagName`, `className`, `id` and `attributes` properties.

So `el` is *resolved* from a selector string (i.e. looked up on the page) or *created* from `tagName` and friends. If you don't bind to a specific existing element then Backbone will create one for you using `tagName`, `className`, ...

If you just have `tagName: 'div'` then the `<div>` your view is bound to is simply the view's `el` and you are responsible for putting that `el` somewhere on the page. Hence the common pattern of:

```
$(some_container).append(view.render().el);
```